# c# make ShowItemToolTips sticky

Tags: c#, listview

I have a ListView where several items have more text than fits in the column width. ShowItemToolTips means i can hover over a column and see the full text which is great.

However, for really long texts, it disappears before there is time to read everything, so i would like to make it stay longer (or possibly until the dismissed manually, eg by moving away the mouse or clicking. How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You know, of course, that underneath the .NET ListView class is a Windows listview control. This listview control uses a Windows tooltip control to show the truncated strings.

You can get hold of this underlying tooltip control through the LVM_GETTOOLTIPS message.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, 
                                        int wParam, int lParam);

public IntPtr GetTooltipControl(ListView lv) {
    const int LVM_GETTOOLTIPS = 0x1000 + 78;
    return SendMessage(lv.handle, LVM_GETTOOLTIPS, 0, 0);
}
```

Once you have the handle to the tooltip control, you can send messages to it.

```
public void SetTooltipDelay(ListView lv, int showTime) {
   const int TTM_SETDELAYTIME = 0x400 + 3;
   const int TTDT_AUTOPOP = 2;

   IntPtr tooltip = this.GetTooltipControl(lv);
   if (tooltip != IntPtr.Zero) {
      SendMessage(tooltip, TTM_SETDELAYTIME, TTDT_AUTOPOP, showTime);
   }
}
```

showTime is the number of milliseconds you want the control to stay visible.

Comment: @Grammarian: Thanks for this - I stumbled upon this answer while searching for something else, and now my product is slightly better than it was five minutes ago.  Wonderful!

Answer (score 2):

There is a pure .NET code alternative to the user32.dll P/Invoke call.  Create a [ToolTip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) control and set all of the delay properties.  Then use the ListView [MouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove.aspx) event to switch the tool tip text based upon the currently selected list view control.

```
    ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
    toolTip.AutoPopDelay = 7000;
    toolTip.InitialDelay = 450;
    toolTip.ReshowDelay = 450;

    listView.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(listView_MouseMove);
```

I gave two options below.  Option #1 sets the tool tip text to Text property of the sub-item.  Option #2 sets the tool tip to the ToolTipText property of the parent ListViewItem.

```
    void  listView_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = listView.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
        ListViewHitTestInfo info = listView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

        if ((item != null) && (info.SubItem != null))
        {
            // Option #1 - Set it to the sub-item text
            // toolTip.SetToolTip(listView, info.SubItem.Text);

            // Option #2 - Sets it to the tool tip text of the sub-item
            toolTip.SetToolTip(listView, info.Item.ToolTipText);
        }
        else
        {
            toolTip.SetToolTip(listView, null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ToolTip class. The AutoPopupDelay method allows you to set the length of time the tooltip remains visible.

Comment: sure, but how do i find the instance to change? (the one automatically generated for subitems with too much text to fit) subitems don't seem to have a tooltip property...