# How do I control how long the tooltip shows for in a PropertyGrid?

Tags: winforms, tooltip, propertygrid

I am hosting a PropertyGrid in our app, when the property value is too large to fit, the PropertyGrid shows a tooltip.

How do I control how long this tooltip is shown for?

Comment: It is locked up in PG internals, GridToolTip class.  Default tooltip times are multiples of the mouse double-click time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [good SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870073/c-make-showitemtooltips-sticky) for how to do this with a ListView, however I have not been able to find an equivalent for how to do it with a PropertyGrid.

Comment: The solution is unlickly to be the same, as the ListView is based on a "standared windows control" and the property grid is not.